# Is there syntax for casting an enum in a match test?

Tags: rust

I have this enum:

```
pub enum SegmentType {
    Code = 0,
    ReadOnly = 1,
    ReadWrite = 2,
    Zp = 3,
    Bss = 4,
    OverWrite = 5,
}
```

And I just read from a database some data that has those enum values as u8 values.

I am trying to do this:

```
match seg.seg_type {
    SegmentType::ReadWrite => {
        for i in seg.start..seg.end {
            shadow[i as usize] = ShadowFlags::READ | ShadowFlags::WRITE;
        }
    }
    SegmentType::ReadOnly => {
        for i in seg.start..seg.end {
            shadow[i as usize] = ShadowFlags::READ;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because seg.seg_type is u8 (of course).

So I tried:

```
SegmentType::ReadOnly as u8 => {
    for i in seg.start..seg.end {
        shadow[i as usize] = ShadowFlags::READ;
    }
}
```

This fails saying 'expected fat arrrow'.

So then I tried:

```
(SegmentType::ReadOnly as u8) => {
    for i in seg.start..seg.end {
        shadow[i as usize] = ShadowFlags::READ;
    }
}
```

This fails saying thats a poorly formed 3 element tuple. I can make it work like this:

```
let rw = SegmentType::ReadWrite as u8;
let ro = SegmentType::ReadOnly as u8; 
match seg.seg_type {
    rw => {
        for i in seg.start..seg.end {
            shadow[i as usize] = ShadowFlags::READ | ShadowFlags::WRITE;
        }
    }
    ..
```

But that's kind of ugly. So there is some syntax that will work in the match test.

Comment: Why isn't `seg.seg_type` of type `SegmentType`? Seems the most idiomatic way.

Comment: *"I can make it work like this"* - the last example *does not work*. It *compiles* but the `rw` in the match is a new binding and not based on the value of `rw` outside the match. If you try to match on both `rw` and `ro`, you'd get a "unreachable arm" warning indicating that. It would work if they were a `const` though.

Comment: @kmdreko yup, I just found that out :-(

Comment: @cafce25 - becuase I just read it out of a database that stores it as u8 .  I suppose I could do the opposite match of u8 to SegmentType before.

Comment: @kmdreko - made const , now works.